# Answer deleted by moderator, but would have preferred edit

Tags: support

I have answered a question about a CDN, and added some clues on how to go further using other existing concurrent services.

As the owner of such a service, I included the link to it, among others, and stated clearly who I am, to let people know I could be biased, as ethics commands me to.

The moderator deleted my answer, and said it was purely promotional. I disagree: It is quite a good answer, or so I think, and maybe only deleting links to products would make it acceptable (or even funnier: If I hadn't said anything about my position as founder of one of the products, I think my answer would still be here, as are some other answers citing commercial products on the same question)

What can I do about it? Is there a way to ask for a vote, or community review, or is one moderator always true? Should I repost my answer, without links? Or repost without stating I'm the owner of one of the solutions?

Here is the problematic answer: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61234/38214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edits look good.   I undeleted your answer and up voted it.

Unfortunately, there are no notifications to me when an edit is made to a question I deleted.  Posting here is meta was appropriate because it can bring this to my attention.

I just [suggested a feature on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231321/can-an-edit-to-a-deleted-question-automatically-raise-a-flag) that would help in this type of situation.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think there should be a way to ask for attention, but I understand that would put much pressure on the moderators...

Comment: The other way to bring something to our attention is to flag it.  I just checked and that can be done after you edit a deleted question.

Comment: Ok, I will think about it. I initially thought that flagging was like saying "this is bad", but well, it isn't. Just, we are more used to flagging for bad behavior than for attention or good behavior.